# "no healthy upstream" error istio routing rule issue

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway

I'm seeing very frequent "no healthy upstream" error on one service calling the other. Due to confidentiality of project cannot share much details.

kubectl pod logs shows something like below:

```
pod1 - restart(1)
pod2 - restart(0) -> throws no healthy upstream error.
```

looks like pod2 trying to connect to pod1 but get the error.

Also, could it be an issue with virtualservice / destination rule.

A newbie here

Answer (score 1):

In [this](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/29254) GitHub issue on the Istio project, you can try and go through the checklist in the issue description to verify that the service components are functional.

There is also a good discussion in the comments section that can help you solve the problem. Something simpler like restarting the ingress gateway has also been known to work.